# Magento2: Receiving a The page you requested was not found eventhough the desired page is found

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.1.5

My Magento 2.1.5 is trowing a "The page you requested was not found, but we have searched for relevant content." displayed on front pages. After clearing sessions and local cache the message goes away but comes back after going through a couple of pages. Weird thing is that served url's and contained content within those urls is correct.

Here's the exact code from I pulled from inspector:

```
<div data-bind="attr: {
        class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
        'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
    }" class="message-notice notice message" data-ui-id="message-notice">
        <div data-bind="html: message.text">The page you requested was not found, but we have searched for relevant content.</div>
    </div>
```

I'm confident this is session related

[image: desktop page not found error]

[image: mobile page not found error]

Comment: <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }" class="message-notice notice message" data-ui-id="message-notice">
            <div data-bind="html: message.text">The page you requested was not found, but we have searched for relevant content.</div>
        </div>

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution of your problem?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

That could be a result of broken URLs (e.g. in the image tags). Such kind of definition within a page will cause "AJAX" search request without any result and give corresponding error message during next reload:
`<img src="https://yousite.com/pub/media/catalog/category/">`.

After cleaning session (and/or cache) it is gone possibly because it's not yet put into the error "pool" so requires a page reload to be surfaced.